# First known/recognized brewery?

Tags: history, breweries

What's the name of the first known/recognized brewery that produced beer (that would be recognized as beer also today)?

Comment: I would suggest reading [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_beer). Your answer is going to depend on what you define as a brewery, and how much information you need. Does it need a name, or is it enough to know that there are recordings of beer brewing in Ebla, Syria in 2500 BCE?

Comment: Brewing beers predates existence of breweries by a significant margin, therefore closing this basing on assumption "first recognized brewery"="first time beer was made" is horribly flawed.

Comment: I don't think these questions are duplicates.  It's possible that the *answers* might be similar (or not), but dupe is about the question, not the answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there's really a good answer to this question. Beer is an ancient beverage, whose formulations and methods of manufacture have changed over the centuries. The oldest continually operating brewery is claimed to be the [Weihenstephan Abbey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weihenstephan_Abbey).